# how to send control + L and control + C to another application?

Tags: c#

I am working on win application using c#, I want to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> when firefox is active, to locate address bar and copy Url and get info from the clipboard. I am trying to do this. but I am not able to do so.

how can I do this?
activate the Firefox window, send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> (activates address bar), send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (copy selection, ie. URL, to clipboard) and read the clipboard.

```
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private const uint VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
    private const uint VK_L = 0x4C;
    private const uint VK_C = 0x43;


if (hwndfirfox == Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")[0].MainWindowTitle)
       hwndfirfox = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")[0].MainWindowHandle;

if (hwndfirfox != null)
{
    PostMessage(hwndfirfox, VK_CONTROL, VK_L, 0);
    PostMessage(hwndfirfox, VK_CONTROL, VK_C, 0);
}
```

this code is giving error, help me .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169732/wmkeydown-how-to-use-it/1169843#1169843) which states that PostMessage shouldn't be used for simulating keyboard input. You should use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(VS.85).aspx) or [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) for this.

Comment: Only reason I'm not downvoting this answer is, because it acknowledges that the OP's solution is the worst way to go about it. Still, `SendKeys`/`SendInput` is almost as bad (it doesn't account for locales, where [Ctrl]+C does not map to a copy operation, for example). If you want to automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx) on CodeProject. The [SendKeys class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) on MSDN only appears to allow you to send keystrokes to the currently active application, which may be helpful to you as well.

Comment: I was going to suggest same code-project article, but went to format code in questin :)