# Send or Post a message to notepad or msword dialog when application ask to save or not

Tags: vb.net, postmessage

The code below shows how to closed an application by filename.
And it closes it without saving a document,
If I point a filename in notepad, it doesn't closed directly, instead asking to save or not.
I want to close the application with saving the document directly.

Any ideas to correct the code?

```
Const WM_Close As UInteger = &H10
    Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
    Const WM_COMMAND = &H112

Private Sub searchnclosedoc(ByVal noextfilename As String, ByVal ms_appname As String)
    For Each wproc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(ms_appname)
        If wproc.MainWindowTitle.Contains(noextfilename) Then
            If PostMessage(wproc.MainWindowHandle, WM_Close, WM_KEYDOWN, Keys.Enter) Then
                'MessageBox.Show("not closed, dialog asked")
                'PostMessage(wproc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_COMMAND, Keys.Enter)
                MyThreadedControl(lbltest, "Text", noextfilename & " was SAVED and CLOSED to Prevent Conflict")
            Else
                MyThreadedControl(lbltest, "Text", noextfilename & " was CLOSED to Prevent Conflict")
            End If
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

This closes msword without asking to saved or not.
This doesn't save the document after closed.
But I want the document to be saved before closing.
And in notepad a dialog box appears asking to saved or not.
I want to close the application and directly saved the documents edited without showing the diaglog box.

```
    PostMessage(wproc.MainWindowHandle, WM_Close, WM_KEYDOWN, Keys.Enter)
```

This is how I used the procedure,

```
           searchnclosedoc(dfilenamewithoutextension, "MSWORD")
           searchnclosedoc(dfilenamewithoutextension, "notepad")
```

I also tried this,

```
Private Sub searchnclosedoc(ByVal noextfilename As String, ByVal ms_appname As String)
    For Each wproc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(ms_appname)
        If wproc.MainWindowTitle.Contains(noextfilename) Then
            If PostMessage(wproc.MainWindowHandle, WM_Close, 0, 0) Then
                'MessageBox.Show("not closed, dialog asked")

                Dim h, h2, h3, h4 As IntPtr
                If ms_appname = "notepad" Then
                    h = FindWindowA(h, "Notepad")
                ElseIf ms_appname = "Foxit Reader" Then
                    h = FindWindowA(h, "Foxit Reader")
                Else
                    h = FindWindowA(h, ms_appname)
                End If

                If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

                If ms_appname = "notepad" Then
                    h2 = FindWindowEx(h, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Yes")
                ElseIf ms_appname = "Foxit Reader" Then
                    h2 = FindWindowEx(h, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&No")
                Else
                    h3 = FindWindowEx(h, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Save")
                End If

                If h2 <> 0 Then h4 = h2 Else h4 = h3
                If h4 <> 0 Then
                    PostMessage(h4, &HF5, 0, 0)
                End If

                MyThreadedControl(lbltest, "Text", noextfilename & " was SAVED and CLOSED to Prevent Conflict")
            Else
                MyThreadedControl(lbltest, "Text", noextfilename & " was CLOSED to Prevent Conflict")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Notepad is not doing well, it saves, sometime it also asked with dialog box,
 The Foxit Reader is Ok, not saving for NO,   The msWORD is not saving and closes directly which I want to closed, saved, closed.

Solved with this code:( I CHANGE THE CODE ) Below.

```
Private Sub searchnclosedoc(ByVal noextfilename As String, ByVal ms_appname As String)
    For Each wproc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(ms_appname)
        If wproc.MainWindowTitle.Contains(noextfilename) Then
            SetForegroundWindow(wproc.MainWindowHandle)
            SendKeys.SendWait("^(s)")
            Thread.Sleep(100)
            SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}")
            Thread.Sleep(100)
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
            MyThreadedControl(lbltest, "Text", noextfilename & " was SAVED and CLOSED to Prevent Conflict")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Using this code for a moment: And its working fine.

```
Private wordApp as New Word.Application
Private Sub searchnclosedoc(ByVal noextfilename As String, ByVal ms_appname As String)
    For Each wproc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(ms_appname)

        If ms_appname.Contains("WINWORD") Then
            If wproc.MainWindowTitle.Contains(noextfilename) Then
                wordapp = DirectCast(GetObject(, "Word.Application"), Word.Application)
                AddHandler wordapp.DocumentBeforeClose, AddressOf WordClose
                PostMessage(wproc.MainWindowHandle, WM_Close, 0, 0)
                MyThreadedControl(lbltest, "Text", noextfilename & " was SAVED and CLOSED to Prevent Conflict")
            End If
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: But, its good to used the Postmessage rather than SendKeys, because Postmessage sends message without setting the application to foreground.  I wonder how to use it with Postmessage. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried send a Ctrl-S before sending WM_Close?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's right, send a Ctrl-S, Ok, I'll try it. thanks

Comment: PostMessage(wproc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, Keys.Control, 0)
                PostMessage(wproc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, Keys.S, 0)

                PostMessage(wproc.MainWindowHandle, WM_Close, 0, 0)

Comment: Please read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176072/how-to-send-control-l-and-control-c-to-another-application

Comment: I also tried this, but it only works IF application is NOT hidden, or the application is in taskbar.                      SetForegroundWindow(wproc.MainWindowHandle)
                SendKeys.SendWait("^(s)")
                SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}")
                PostMessage(wproc.MainWindowHandle, WM_Close, 0, 0)