# SendKeys with games: with some characters it works, but with some it doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, input, sendkeys

I want to simulate input in games with **SendKeys**, but I have a hard time.

If I use it with i.e. the letter **T**, while the cursor in Minecraft is in a textbox (in the main menu), it works, the letter T is written in the textbox.

But with **{ESC}** it doesn't work. Nothing happens. If I press it manually, it backs to the previous menu. (as it should)

**With some applications ESC works:**

- It works with Discord, Sourcetree, Slack, Chrome, CS2D,
- but for some reason it doesn't work with Minecraft, Spelunky, Half-Life.

All of the applications mentioned above were in **windowed mode**.

**Another issue:**

- If I send **2** to Minecraft while in a text field, it works correctly, 2 is written.
- But if I send it while I'm playing, there is no effect. (The character should switch to Item Slot #2)
- Same with " " **(whitespace)**. In text fields it works, but the character won't jump in the game.

**Code:**

```
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IntPtr minecraftHandle = FindWindow("GLFW30", "Minecraft* 1.15.2");

        if (minecraftHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Minecraft is not running.");
            return;
        }

        SetForegroundWindow(minecraftHandle);
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
    }
```

I tried it without focus switching: by assigning the **SendKey calls to a hotkey**, so the target application can be in focus when the SendKeys are called.

The results are the same :\

Comment: Have you tried adding `<appSettings> <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/> 
</appSettings>` to `App.config` (or calling [SendInput()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) directly)?

Comment: I added this app settings under configuration, but didn't help. How could I call SendInput() directly?

Comment: If you added `<add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>` correctly to `App.config`, you already did. With that setting, `SendKeys.SendWait()` calls `SendInput()`. I have no idea what `Esc` is supposed to do here (close a Window, maybe?), so you have to test other ways. -- You said that `SetForegroundWindow` works, so  (since it might not), maybe the app is expecting something different or the currently focuses object doesn't bubble up the key press, or...

Comment: Oh, I see. Then it doesn't work either :\ (Letter T is still working)

Comment: If you're trying to close a Window, maybe send `WM_CLOSE` (with `SendMessage`, of course), see if that works.

Comment: That works: the windows is instantly closed.

Comment: @Jimi Turns out it works with other applications, and with Minecraft it doesn't.

Comment: @Jimi I edited the post again, I got even more clues.

Comment: I have tried https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator which let's you simulate KeyDown/KeyUp as well. While in console normal chars are written. ESC and ENTER don't have an effect. Don't know why. DirectX/OpenGL problem? Idk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do not use `SendKeys.Send` to messaging between processes working on different runtimes**

`SendKeys.Send` method is from `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

This means it is not a *Windows Input simulator*, but just a little helper for Windows Forms applications. There is no guarantee this method work with another process on different (not .NET) runtime system.

Despite the fact that `SendKeys.Send` method uses [native Windows API](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/SendKeys.cs,2c0710ad7203a696), it send key pressing message only of **fixed period of time**, so game frame handling may not have time to catch this message to manage it. So you may need for separate commands to send message about key down and key up events.

Do not use `SendKeys` API for messaging with another processes, **especially with games**.
*Also, games can use protection system to rid of automatic bots that can blocks any messages from operation system programming input*

#### So, what you can use?

First, you can try to use `PostMessage` of `user32.dll` system library:

```
const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

// hWnd - Window handler (can be getted by using GetForegroundWindow/FindWindow methods)
// msg - Key up/down message (WM_KEYUP / WM_KEYDOWN)
// wParam - Virual key code you need to pass to the window
// lParam - Additional parameter for set up key message behaviour.
```

All virtual key codes can be found on microsoft docs website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Don't forget that you need to wait some time before key releasing. This is needed because games cache inputs between frames, and frame has fixed time to catch input. Just write some delay between key down and up messages.

Also you can set up key message behaviour by *lParam*. See [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown#parameters) and [WM_KEYUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup#parameters) parameters. Special thing about WM_KEYDOWN message is if you pressing key on real keyboard long time, operation system repeating WM_KEYDOWN message accordingly. Repeating count can be setted up through lParam. Use it if window you messaging does not react on single keydown message.

`PostMessage` is low-level system command that can be used for messaging between processes. This command has a low probability to be blocked by protection system (but not zero) and high probability to be received by the game/process you working with. Also it provides opportunity to separate key up and key down messages.

#### What if `PostMessage` didn't work?

Try to use **hardware scan code** instead of **virtual key code**. Detailed explanation how you can do that described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811061/9262535).

If protection system is really good and `PostMessage` is blocking even if you use hardware scan code, one thing you can try is to **use another keyboard input driver** or write it yourself. That driver must replace default system keyboard driver. And you can message it to interact with game. This is the **100% guarantee** way to interact with other process through keyboard. But if you use public custom keyboard drivers, there is some probability that protection system blocks it. So you need to write your own driver to message between processes.

Comment: The **only** guaranteed way? *There is no guarantee this method work with another process on different (not .NET) runtime system.* The WinForm SendKeys method uses an unmanaged native method:  `eventsSent += UnsafeNativeMethods.SendInput(1, currentInput, INPUTSize);`, its line 655 here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/SendKeys.cs,2c0710ad7203a696

Comment: @JeremyThompson native `SendInput` method calling directly on foreground window **only**, while code in question operate with window handler. `PostMessage` method can be used even if target window not in foreground, so it's just more flexible and low-level solution.

Comment: @JeremyThompson and yes, self-developed keyboard driver is the **only, 100% guaranteed** way to pass key pressing to other windows. If you have any other thinks about it, it will be nice if you share it with me and community.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but there are also options between `PostMessage()` and  writing your own keyboard driver such as [keybd_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event)

Comment: Sadly it still doesn't work with ESC with Spelunky and Minecraft. (But i.e. with the letter "t" it works this way as well. Could it be possible that all these games have these kind of protections? But with Diablo, ESC, and any input works with SendKeys and PostMessage as well.

Comment: By the way, I tried only with the KEYDOWN, because ESC functions in these example games as soon as I press down the button, it won't wait for a release So I think it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Guys, is Minecraft DirectX or OpenGL? The former doesn't receive Ring 3 commands.

Comment: Now I correctly calculated an lParam, instead of just passing 0 as you suggested, and now it seems to work. Hopefully will pass the further tests as well.

Comment: @Tudvari I'll perform some other research and will update my answer according your information. Thank you.

Comment: I got the solution here, maybe it could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280000/how-to-create-lparam-of-sendmessage-wm-keydown

Comment: @Tudvari i've updated my answer accordingly. You can check it above.

Comment: @JeremyThompson as I know Minecraft working on OpenGL tech.

Comment: In my case its pretty silly because im trying to use this with a single player game, and i have a hard time to get it to work. I think maybe they use some out of the box anti-cheat system despite it being single player. Im just trying to add some convenience functions, i can activate auto-run by pressing num-lock.